# Does "along" mean "but" in this sentence: "That effort too came to nothing, along she insists with appeals to US Embassy staff in Riyadh."

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC web site, [Trapped in Saudi Arabia: A mother's fight to free her daughter](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-62903758)

> That effort too came to nothing, along she insists with appeals to US Embassy staff in Riyadh.

What does *along* mean here? Does it mean *but/however*? I checked 2 dictionaries and the word *along* does not seem to have such a meaning.

Comment: Not idiomatically correct in American English. We would expect "although" here.

Comment: @keshlam: It is actually fine, but reads oddly the way it is punctuated - putting the "she insists" in parentheses (or even between commas) would make it much easier to parse!

Comment: @psmears I would say that it is not fine.  Commas are absolutely necessary here

Comment: That's just sloppy writing, equally so in AmE and BrE. Without the commas, the sentence barely makes sense at all.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's all down to how the sentence is parsed:

> That effort too came to nothing, along she insists with appeals to US Embassy staff in Riyadh.

I hope these parentheses make it clearer:

> That effort too came to nothing, along (she insists) with appeals to US Embassy staff in Riyadh.

So it is *"along with appeals to ..."*

Neither writing to the White House, nor appealing to the embassy, produced any result.

Comment: I would have written it with a comma, parenthesis, or em dash before 'she insists' and another one after.

Comment: Yes. For "along with" you can substitute "as well as" or "together with". Perhaps a better way to write it would be *That effort, together with appeals to US Embassy staff, came to nothing - she insisted*.

Comment: Nice answer. I was ready to declare this one simply bad grammar.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I would argue it is nonstandard not to indicate some sort of punctuation. It doesn't make sense even verbally without a pause.

Comment: Yes, “she insists” should absolutely have been offset with commas on either side. Without, it’s wrong as written. But this is near-certainly what was meant.

Comment: My guess is that this is a transcript of a report given over the radio or television, where the phrasing would be made more obvious by the intonation of the speaker.  It doesn't work in print without some punctuation, but when spoken correctly it might make more sense.

Comment: That's the only way I can make it make sense, short of mistranscription or misuse. Well done!

Comment: The parenthetical clause has no business interrupting the "along with", regardless of what punctuation is (not) used. "That effort, too, came to nothing, along with (she insists) appeals to US Embassy staff in Riyadh."

Comment: @Martha I added the parentheses to help with the parsing, not the grammar. The OP asks what the sentence means, and the 'grammar' tag was deleted.

Answer (score -1):

No, along does not mean but. But the sentence is poor, as mentioned in the other answer.

"Nor did" would be better English, as it is negative. "Along with" is positive but "came to nothing" is negative:

That effort too came to nothing, nor did appeals to US Embassy staff in Riyadh.

If you must have "she insists" it should be after a comma right at the end.

Comment: No.  Came "came to nothing" is positive.  "Did not come to anything" would be the corresponding negative.  Therefore, the suggested use of "nor did" is incorrect, and indeed it sounds awkward, though it probably gets the idea across better than the original sentence.  One correct phrasing would be "That effort too came to nothing, *as did* appeals to US Embassy staff in Riyadh."